# MongoDB hadoop connector fails to query on mongo hive table

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, mongodb-hadoop, bigdata

I am using MongoDB hadoop connector to query mongoDB using hive table in hadoop.

I am able to execute

```
select * from mongoDBTestHiveTable;
```

But when I try to execute following query

```
select id from mongoDBTestHiveTable;
```

it throws following exception.

Following class exist in hive lib folder.

Exception stacktrace:

```
    Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot create an instance of InputSplit class = com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat$MongoHiveInputSplit:Class com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat$MongoHiveInputSplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat$HiveInputSplit.readFields(HiveInputFormat.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat$MongoHiveInputSplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat$HiveInputSplit.readFields(HiveInputFormat.java:144)
    ... 10 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
```

Please advice.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add mongo-hadoop-* and well as mongo driver jars to MR1/MR2 classpath on all workers

Comment: Yes these jars are present in hadoop installation directory and in hive classpath

Comment: I have used 1.3.0 jars for hadoop 2.2 and is working fine.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/kVil7uIJEhw